# warning in yii form submission

Tags: php, yii

Is there is any way to get only `warning` in `yii` like

I have a `form`

```
<?php
/* @var $this UserController */
/* @var $model User */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
     'enableClientValidation' => true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>    

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mobile'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'mobile',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>20)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'mobile'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I know if i want `unique` mobile number then i have to define unique `rule` for it in `Model` but i want that when a mobile number is entered which already exist then i just get an `warning` message but `form` submission is allowed .

So I tried this

User.php

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return array(
           array('mobile', 'checkDublicateExist', 'on'=>'createuser'),
        );
    }


    public function checkDublicateExist($attribute,$params)
    {            

        if(!empty($this->mobile)){
          $count = User::Model()->count("mobile=:mobile", array("mobile" => $this->mobile));
       if($count){
          $this->addError('mobile' 'This mobile already exist!');
          return true;
       }

    }
}
```

I return true for by pass this `validation` but this will not allowing me to submit form. I only want warning for user

Answer (score 0):

You can set message like this

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notice', "This mobile already exist!");
```